# base64_encode conflict with convert_smilies in wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development, api

I am trying to show image in my wordpress website which get from third-party. They give me raw data of image. For showimg image, I need to convert raw data(which get from third-party) to `base64_encode`. It was working perfectly but recently got an error with a specific image. For all other image is working perfectly.

I have debug and found the issue was create for `base64_encode($file)`.

**My Code :**

```
$file = "image raw data which get form third-party";
$type = "image type"; // png, jpg, jpeg
$en_data = base64_encode($file);
<img src="data:image/<?=$type;?>;base64, <?= $en_data; ?> ">
```

**Error :**

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be
> of type Countable|array, bool given in
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\formatting.php:3415 Stack trace: #0
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(307):
> convert_smilies('\r\n<style type="...') #1
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\plugin.php(191):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters('\r\n<style type="...', Array) #2
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\post-template.php(253):
> apply_filters('the_content', '<!-- wp:shortco...') #3
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\pagetemplate\page_fullwidth-template.php(11):
> the_content() #4
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106):
> include('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #5
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-blog-header.php(19):
> require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #6
> E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\index.php(17): require('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #7
> {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-includes\formatting.php on
> line 3415
>
> There has been a critical error on this website.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code from formatting.php

```php
if ( get_option( 'use_smilies' ) && ! empty( $wp_smiliessearch ) ) {
    // HTML loop taken from texturize function, could possible be consolidated.
    $textarr = preg_split( '/(<.*>)/U', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE ); // Capture the tags as well as in between.
    $stop    = count( $textarr ); // Loop stuff.
```

The problem is [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is failing. Its documentation says it returns false on failure, but the code here isn't checking for that and feeding the result straight into count(). I'm not sure how to get more details of the preg_split failure. And arguably WordPress should cope with that and skip the smiley step here.

However I'd guess it's because your encoded image is huge and that's causing problems in general. Your simplest option is probably to disable convert_smilies(), either by clearing the use_smilies option or removing the filter

```php
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies', 20 );
```

but I think your best bet would be to handle the image differently: ideally don't keep it in memory if it's large - stream it to disk and then fetch the image from an endpoint that reads that back in. However I appreciate that might get complicated quickly, depending on the page flow here: whether this page makes the web service call you're now trying to separate out into a separate request + so who owns the completion of that call, protecting / cleaning up the images downloaded, potentially sharing them between a cluster of WordPress servers (which might need a separate file share to keep these out of wp_uploads) etc.

Comment: Thanks @Rup :)
It's work for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rup!
I've been struggling with this for days. My problem was I couldn't edit some WP pages.
Your line of code on functions.php solved the issue!
I hope someone can fix this. Unfortunately I don't know which component is causing this, so I can't report properly.